# Site does not work on a ipad 8.4.1 but works on newer ipads, or Android or pc

Tags: javascript, ios, ipad, syntax-error, unexpected-token

I get this error:
`SyntaxError: Unexpected token '>'`
at this line:

```
const isUsingDevice = (devices,value) => devices.some(d => value.includes(d));
```

How can I make the site not crash at this line, on older iOS devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I get this error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '>' at this line:

That's because Safari 9.x doesn't support `arrow functions` feature of ES6 (ES2015) which you employ in this statement:

```
(devices,value) => devices.some(d => value.includes(d))
```

BTW, it also provides just a basic support for `const` feature. You can check the whole picture [here](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/).

> How can I make the site not crash at this line, on older iOS devices?

Use transpiler ([babel](https://babeljs.io/) or else) to transform the code written in ES6 into ES5 flavor.

Comment: Thanks! I had my thoughts that it might be from ES6, but being a beginner to javascript, I wasn't sure